# Passing serialized Externalizable object from standard JVM to CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to deserialize an object, which:

- was created and serialized in another standard JVM (server)
- implements traditional Java Externalizable interface
- was passed over a network

> ```
> public static void getData() {  
>     ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {  
>         @Override  
>             protected void readResponse(InputStream is) throws IOException {  
>             DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);  
>             Employee recovered = new Employee();  
>             recovered.internalize(1, dis);  
>         }  
>     };  
>     req.setUrl(BASEURL);  
>     req.setPost(false);  
>     NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
> }
> ```

From the remote jvm I'm passing object in ByteArray or ByteArrayInputStream and in CN1 I get EOFException.

Is it possible to transfer objects such way? Or should i use JSON.
I thought I don't need JSON, if I have Java on both sides..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One's externalization interface isn't compatible with Java SE. Serialization and externalization relies on reflection and dynamic invocation which aren't practical on all of Codename One's targets (even Android where the binary is usually obfuscated).

You can pass an object however you will need to use the Codename One API to do so. You can effectively take the JavaSE.jar file from the Codename one project and use the API there to write/read the object.

Other than that your code to read the object is incorrect. You should use Util.readObject/writeObject. I suggest reading the [great tutorial Steve Hannah wrote on the subject](http://sjhannah.com/blog/?p=234).